# react-admin, how do I notify store that some resource is updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

For example, I have a resource `Worker`, with a property `progress`

On Worker's SHOW page, I have a custom button that send request to server, server does some work and returns the updated progress. So how do it either:

1) update UI's `progress` value without leaving/refresh page, something like `store.dispatch(value_updated_action(newValue))`(preferred)

or

2) refresh SHOW page on callback.